# Effective picking of surrounded element

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, matrix-indexing

If I have sequence `1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1`
how to effectively locate zero which has from both sides 1.

In this sequence it means zero on position 6 and 8. The ones in bold.

1 0 0 0 1 **0** 1 **0** 1 1 1

I can imagine algorithm that would loop through the array and look one in back and one in front I guess that means O(n) so probably there is not any more smooth one.

If you can find another way, I am interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html):

```
pos = strfind(X(:)', [1 0 1]) + 1
```

Note that this will work only when `X` is a vector.

#### Example

```
X = [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ];
pos = strfind(X(:)', [1 0 1]) + 1
```

The result:

```
pos =
     6     8
```

Answer (score 2):

The `strfind` method that @EitanT suggested is quite nice.  Another way to do this is to use `find` and element-wise bit operations:

```
% let A be a logical ROW array
B = ~A & [A(2:end),false] & [false,A(1:end-1)];
elements = find(B);
```

This assumes, based on your example, that you want to exclude boundary elements.  The concatenations `[A(2:end),false]` and `[false,A(1:end-1)]` are required to keep the array length the same.  If memory is a concern, these can be eliminated:

```
% NB: this will work for both ROW and COLUMN vectors
B = ~A(2:end-1) & A(3:end) & A(1:end-2);
elements = 1 + find(B);  % need the 1+ because we cut off the first element above
```

Answer (score 0):

...and to elaborate on @Eitan T 's answer, you can use strfind for an array if you loop by row

```
% let x = some matrix of 1's and 0's (any size)
[m n] = size(x);
for r = 1:m;
  pos(r,:) = strfind(x(r,:)',[1 0 1]) + 1;
end
```

pos would be a m x ? matrix with m rows and any returned positions. If there were no zeros in the proper positions though, you might get a NaN ... or an error. Didn't get a chance to test.